# Properties of moment generating functions

Tags: probability-theory, moment-generating-functions, actuarial-science

Let $X$ be a random variable with density $f(x)=2x\cdot I_{0\le x\le 1}$, a cdf $F(x)=I_{\{x>1\}}+x^2I_{\{0\le x\le 1\}}$ and let $F_I(x):=1/\mu\int_0^x (1-F(y))dy$ where $\mu=E[X]$

(Note: $F_I$ is again a distribution function.)

---

I try to find a **short** argument that the moment generating function of $F_I$

which is $\hat{f_I}(t)=\int_0^\infty e^{tx}dF_I(x)= 1/\mu\int_0^x e^{tx}(1-F(y))dy$

hits a value $K>1$, i.e. $\exists t\in \mathbb R$ such that $\hat{f_I}(t)=K>1$ where $K$ is arbitrary.

This condition is called the small claims condition in the Cramér-Lundberg model. This question concerns the existence of the so called adjustment coefficient.

If we consider an arbitrary moment generating function $\hat{f}$ of a random variable.
If $\hat{f}(t)<\infty \quad \forall t>0$ then the adjustment coefficient exists, i.e. $\exists t\in \mathbb R$ such that $\hat{f_I}(t)=K>1$ where $K>1$ is arbitrary. So what does the existence of a mgf imply for the existence of the adjustment coefficient?

---

I try to formulate a differential equation in the interval (0,1) for
$\Phi(x):=\Phi(0)+\frac{\lambda}{c}\int_0^x \Phi(x-y)(1-F(y))dy$ by differentiating it once.

I used that the convolution is commutative and then by Leibniz rule
$\Phi'(x)=\frac{\lambda}{c}\int_0^x \Phi(y)\frac{d}{dx}(1-F(x-y))dy + \frac{\lambda}{c}\Phi(u)(1-F(0))=\frac{\lambda}{c}\int_0^x \Phi(y)\frac{d}{dx}[1-(x-y)^2]dy + \frac{\lambda}{c}\Phi(u)=-2\frac{\lambda}{c}\int_0^x \Phi(y)(x-y)dy + \frac{\lambda}{c}\Phi(u)$

You see I can't made a differential equation of that.

Comment: So, you re trying to show that $\hat f_I$ hits $K$ if and only if $\hat f_I$ hits $K$? // Anyway, why not compute $\hat f_I(t)$ and solve $\hat f_I(t)=K$ for $t$?

Comment: Is for any moment generating function that satisfies $\hat f (t)< \infty \quad \forall t>0$ $\lim_{t \to \infty} \hat{f_I}(t) = \infty$?

Comment: Try $$E(e^{tX})\geqslant e^{tx}P(X\geqslant x)$$ for every $x>0$ such that $P(X\geqslant x)\ne0$.

Comment: Can you help me with the lower part of my problem (the differential equation)?

Comment: Recall first that $$\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^xg(x,y)dy=g(x,x)+\int_0^x\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(x,y)dy$$ Then, you define $$\Phi(x)=\Phi(0)+a\int_0^x(1-F(y))\Phi(x-y)dy$$ or, equivalently, $$\Phi(x)=\Phi(0)+a\int_0^x(1-F(x-y))\Phi(y)dy$$
where $F'=f$ and $F(0)=1$, hence $$\Phi'(x)=a\Phi(x)-a\int_0^xf(x-y)\Phi(y)dy$$ In the present case, $f(x)=2x$ for every $x$ in $(0,1)$ hence $$\Phi'(x)=a\Phi(x)-2ax\int_0^x\Phi(y)dy+2a\int_0^xy\Phi(y)dy$$
wich yields $$\Phi''(x)=a\Phi'(x)-2a\int_0^xy\Phi(y)dy$$
and, finally, $$\Phi^{(3)}(x)=a\Phi''(x)-2ax\Phi(x)$$

Comment: Thanks Did for answering all my questions! I think it should be $\Phi''(x)=a\Phi'(x)-2a\int_0^x\Phi(y)dy$

Comment: Absolutely. Well spotted! (Hence $-2a\Phi(x)$ instead of $-2ax\Phi(x)$ one line later.)